# Java: Threading: Add Element with ID to list from different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have different threads from which I want to call a function that adds an element to a list by finding the current highest ID, incrementing it and inserting the new object (with the incremented ID) into the list.

Do I have to care that, when two threads call the function at the same time, two objects will have the same ID or does the JVM take care of this

Comment: Please show us how you access the list and determine the highest ID. Based on the current information I'd say yes, you do have to take care of that.

Comment: You will definitely have `to care`. This could easily be implemented in a way that produces multiple id's of the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use operations like ++ or += 1, those take multiple steps to work, and if the steps get interleaved with operations called by another thread on that field then the threads can interfere with esch other and the field may get some unexpected value.

Also the process of finding the highest id and inserting a new value in the list is not something you want interfered with by other threads.  You would need to acquire a lock before finding the high value and hold onto it until you're done inserting the new entry.

If you use the Atomic classes, their methods cannot be interfered with (that's what Atomic means).  Using AtomicLong.incrementAndGet() will result in each call returning the next long value.

It would be better to use an atomic variable or a database sequence than to mess with searching for the highest id (and having to lock) repeatedly. In applications that use methods to generate ids like what you describe, id generation can be a bottleneck.